# Configuring Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers in Windows 8. But I don't know how to configure it. Do I need to install any other compilers for that? And what are the other steps to run c/c++ programs successfully?

Comment: Yes, you need some C++ compiler, perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). (Eclipse is not a compiler). BTW, you could use an editor (e.g. `emacs`) instead. And learn how to compile on the command line (since every compiler is command driven)

Comment: How can I install GCC in a Windows 8 machine and how to configure it with Eclipse?

Comment: Maybe you need Cygwin or MinGw. I don't know and don't use Windows so I don't know the details. And you should make sure your compiler is working on the command line.